# What is the function of the Indus Worm's teeth?

Tags: creature-design, anatomy

The indus worm is an animal that lives in the Indus River. It is around 10ft long, and resembles a legless caterpillar. It is semiaquatic, sleeping in the riverbed during the day and hunting on land at night. Its hunting style is similar to a large snake, and it mainly eats mid-sized ungulates such as horses and camels. Its teeth are unique: They are 15 inches long and square. There are only 2 teeth, one in each jaw, giving it a resemblance to rodents. While rodent-like teeth can be very useful for gnawing through various foods and materials, this function doesn't seem all that relevent to the indus worm

What is the most reasonable function for these teeth to have?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Because slicing plant matter is what they used to do

Before I begin, I'd like to say that I assumed it has a skull or at least some kind of internal or external support system for these teeth, since it has teeth and apparently digs them into its prey (even cephalopods have hard support areas to anchor their beaks to).

With that said, rather than rats, let's look at koalas, shall we? [image]

Looking at those teeth we can see the koala has, as you say, rodent-like incisors, however, they don't use it to gnaw, they use it to shear. Koala incisors are adapted to shear the eucalyptus trees they feed on, and because of that need to slice the fibrous leaves, they can be pretty sharp. By looking at koalas, it's not impossible that your worm once fed on leaves from trees that grew near the river, using its 2 sharp teeth to slice them into small bits, at which point it'd go to sleep in the river to reduce energy consumption, because digesting fibrous plant matter can demand a lot of energy.

However, as time passed, the region near the Indus River, main habitat of the worm, suffered some changes, with most of the top predators going extinct, leaving the niche vacant. Being normally large in size and already accustomed to a semiaquatic lifestyle, the worms easily adapted to also fill the niche of semiaquatic apex predator, its teeth changing in function from shearing plant matter to stabbing and slicing through flesh.

And at this point, it might seem stupid that koala-like teeth would be effective for hunting prey instead of the good old leaf munching, and so I present to you an animal that went through a very similar process, except that instead of coming from the water, it came from the top of trees: enter Thylacoleo carnifex.

[image]

From this skull we can look well at the changes to the dentistion of theylacoleo, who came to be from a previously herbivorous species, into one of the apex predators of its time. It's incisors took the job of canines from most modern predators, being used to stab its prey. Thylacoleo's small brain also allowed its skull to take a very particular shape, maximizing its bite strength and giving it the title of strongest mammalian bite in history. Of course though, thylacoleo also kept its molars, which also adapted to work as scissors, slicing the flesh of its prey into bits small enough to eat.

## Or...

Alternatively, we could bypass this problem of having stabbing teeth, but not slicing teeth by making it so this worm had no real teeth whatsoever. For that however, we consider another apex predator which also had a somewhat Rondent-like look from the right angle: Dunkleosteus terreli.

[image]

Dunkleosteus terreli was another apex predator of its time, except that while thylacoleo had to make do with the teeth it's herbivorous ancestry granted it, dunkelosteus had no teeth whatsoever. The tooth-like protrusions in dunkleosteus jaw area were not real teeth, but rather literal bony protrusions which would constantly grow and rasp against one another, keeping them perpetually sharp. Dunkleosteus needed such sharpness, particularly at its younger ears, because the juveniles did not have the jaw power of the adults and weren't very capable at hunting hard-shelled prey. Instead they hunted softer prey like sharks, their powerful yet incredibly fast bites creating a vacuum that would pull prey partially in, with its sharp plates clamping down like a guillotine and guaranteeing a meal. These sharpened plates combined with a powerful jaw resulted in a bite that, when measured in psi, rivals even that of the mighty T-rex, slicing prey apart with little to no effort.

So summing up, we can go down on 2 potential paths for your worm:

1-it once fed on leaves which it sheared into tiny bits with its sharp incisor-like teeth. A lack of competing carnivores in the region and overabundance of prey that'd come near the river allowed them to fill in the niche of crodile-esque predator, adapting its shearing teeth to stab prey and pull it underwater. It might have even learned how to do a death roll, or something similar to an eel's death knot.

2- it actually has no teeth whatsoever and was never a herbivore, instead, it has a Number of sharp bony protrusions coming from its powerful Jaws, which it uses to literally clamp down on and slice apart prey. The need to ensure even a less effective bite, as well as it's habit of also preying on harder shelled animals resulted in similar configuration and front protrusions to that of dunkleosteus, giving it a remotely rodent-like appearance (although much more fearsome in my opinion).

Answer (score 1):

## How does a 10ft long caterpillar kill an 8ft long horse that doesn't need to slither to move?

Your 15 inch long folding teeth are attached to a folding jaw like a bear trap. The Indus worm is an ambush predator that impales the larger animal with its huge teeth, then curls its soft, vulnerable body up around its prey. If the bite doesn't immediately puncture a vital organ, it clings to its prey. Square teeth resist being pulled out of the prey, with more surface than rounded teeth. The prey, with a pair of 15 inch deep wounds constantly being aggravated, slowly dies. Meanwhile, a rasp-tongue allows the Indus worm to eat their prey while still alive and drink its blood. The massive jaws keep the worm attached firmly. Even if predators come and take down the horse/camel, the Indus worm has already gotten a nice meal of horseflesh. The enormous fangs also provide an impressive display to ward off predators who might be tempted to eat your worm.